# Getting Nomenclature To work

Tags: packages, nomenclature, nomencl

I know there are already several threads on this, but I've given everything a try, I was hoping to see if anyone had additional imput. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to put this page in my thesis before the first chapter but after the list of figures and tables. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{nomencl} \makenomenclature \begin{document} 
\section*{Main equations} 
\begin{equation} 
a=\frac{N}{A} 
\end{equation}% 
\nomenclature{$a$}{number of angels per unit area}% 
\nomenclature{$N$}{number of angels per needle point}% 
\nomenclature{$A$}{area of the needle point}% 
The equation $\sigma = m a$% 
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{total mass of angels}% 
\nomenclature{$m$}{mass of one angel} follows easily. 
\printnomenclature 
\end{document}
```

[image: This is a screenshot of just the basic demo text presented in other threads. I also show that the package is present and I tried running the makeindex command manually]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Posting screen shots of code is very awkward -- you can add the code instead and mark up with CTRL-K

Comment: Thank you Christian. Here is the code, I didn't write it myself, it is found when you download the package: 

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature{$a$}{number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{total mass of angels}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{mass of one angel}
follows easily.
\printnomenclature
\end{document}`

Comment: Assuming that your file is called `foo.tex`: Did you run `makeindex -s nomencl.ist foo.nlo -o foo.nls` and then compile again? This works for me!

Comment: Is there any news here?